# $W$ white balls, $B$ black balls, adding $K$ of the resultant color each iteration. What is the probability of getting Black ball in nth iteration.

Tags: probability

[$W$ white balls, $B$ black balls, adding $K$ of the resultant color each iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81958/w-white-balls-b-black-balls-adding-k-of-the-resultant-color-each-iterati?rq=1)

The problem is stated as follows. We have a box with $W$ white balls and $B$ black ones. Repeat N times: each iteration a ball is taken out (uniformly), and put back along with $K$ (constant) more balls of the same color.

I am able to calculate the probabilty but am unable to derive a formula.

Before the first addition: $$P\left(\text{Black}\right) = B/(W + B)$$

In the next iteration:

$$P(\text{black considering two possibilities in previous iteration}) = \frac{B+K}{W + B + K} + \frac{B}{W + B + K}$$

Comment: Try and find some information about _Polya's urn problem._

Comment: The probability of drawing a black ball on the second iteration is not given by your expression; it’s $$\frac{B+K}{B+W+K}\cdot\frac{B}{B+W}+\frac{B}{B+W+K}\cdot\frac{W}{B+W}=\frac{B}{B+W}\;.$$ However, I’m not sure exactly what you’re asking. A formula for what?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, so I'm going to solve for the expected value of the number of balls of each color after a number of iterations.

---

Let $B_n$ be the number of black balls after $n$ iterations of this addition process. Define $W_n$ similarly. $K$ is a fixed constant.

The $B$ and $W$ given are $B_0$ and $W_0$, respectively.

We want to derive a recursive formula for the expected value of $B_{n+1}$ and $W_{n+1}$, given the expected values of $B_n$ and $W_n$. We will then attempt to derive a closed form expression from the recursion.

---

Let $P(A)$ denote the probability that the event $A$ occurs. We begin with the first iteration:

$$E(B_1) = B_0 \cdot P\left(\text{white ball is chosen}\right) + \left(B_0+K\right)\cdot P\left(\text{black ball is chosen}\right)$$

$$E(B_1) = B_0 \cdot \frac{W_0}{B_0 + W_0} + \left(B_0 + K\right) \cdot \frac{B_0}{B_0 + W_0}$$

$$E(B_1) = \frac{\left(B_0\right)\left(B_0 + W_0 + K\right)}{B_0 + W_0}$$

$$E(W_1) = W_0 \cdot P\left(\text{black ball is chosen}\right) + \left(B_0+K\right)\cdot P\left(\text{white ball is chosen}\right)$$

$$E(W_1) = W_0 \cdot \frac{B_0}{B_0 + W_0} + \left(W_0 + K\right) \cdot \frac{W_0}{B_0 + W_0}$$

$$E(W_1) = \frac{\left(W_0\right)\left(B_0 + W_0 + K\right)}{B_0 + W_0}$$

Note that $E(B_1) + E(W_1) = B_0 + W_0 + K$, as it should.

Now, assume that $E(B_n)$ and $E(W_n)$ are known. Because I'm lazy, I'll use $B_n$ and $W_n$ for their expected values.

$$E\left(B_{n+1}\right) = B_n \cdot P\left(\text{white ball is chosen}\right) + \left(B_n + K\right) \cdot P\left(\text{black ball is chosen}\right)$$

$$E\left(B_{n+1}\right) = B_n \cdot \frac{W_n}{B_n+W_n}+ \left(B_n + K\right) \cdot \frac{B_n}{B_n+W_n}$$

Note that $B_n + W_n = B_0 + W_0 + nK$. Substitute this in to get:

$$E\left(B_{n+1}\right) = B_n \cdot \frac{W_n}{B_0+W_0 + nK}+ \left(B_n + K\right) \cdot \frac{B_n}{B_0+W_0 + nK}$$

$$E\left(B_{n+1}\right) = \frac{\left(B_n\right)\left(B_n+W_n+ K\right)}{B_0+W_0 + nK}$$

$$E\left(B_{n+1}\right) = B_n \cdot \frac{B_0+W_0 + \left(n+1\right)K}{B_0+W_0 + nK}$$

Similarly,

$$E\left(W_{n+1}\right) = W_n \cdot \frac{B_0+W_0 + \left(n+1\right)K}{B_0+W_0 + nK}$$

Note that $E(B_{n+1}) + E(W_{n+1}) = B_0 + W_0 + \left(n+1\right)K$, as should intuitively be true (after $n+1$ iterations, there should be $(n+1)K$ more balls than the starting amount).

---

The last two centered formulas above are all the information needed to [derive a closed form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) for each of the expected values.

EDIT: I think solving the recursion might be a bit tricky :(

Comment: You did a lot of work, thanks for that. But what I really wanted was to get a formula to get the probability of getting black ball in n-th iteration or in (n+1)th iteration. Which as I have now found out is same in every iteration.